# decode firebase oobCode to user on server side

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Having some issues regarding a custom email flow and how to decode users on the backend.

see flow:

**user: (webapp)**

1. enter email address and send request for a password reset

**server:**

1. generate oobCode using nodeJS SDK: `admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email);`
2. send link in custom email to user

**user: (webapp)**

1. clicks link -> [www.example.com?oobCode=XYZ](http://www.example.com?oobCode=XYZ)
2. client SDK verify's token has not expired:   `firebase.auth().verifyPasswordResetCode("XYZ");`
3. if valid send oobCode and new password back to server

**Here is where the issue now occurs**

I have sent the new password and the oobCode back to the server, below is the required functionality

server:
**1. verify oobCode and get user uid**

I see no methods to be able to decode this in the backend to verify the user how do I go about getting a user from this code on the backend? it seems we can generate but not decode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this code to verify oobCode for password reset:

```
const passResetUrl = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:resetPassword?key=${firebaseWebApiKey}`
return fetch(passResetUrl, { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ "oobCode": oobCode, newPassword: "newpass" }), headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }).then(async (res) => {
  const resJson = await res.json()
  //const email = resJson.email
  console.log(resJson)
  return "ok"
}).catch((errVerifyingCode) => {
  console.log(errVerifyingCode)
  return "error"
})
```

The firebaseWebApiKey can be found in your web app's Firebase configuration.

If by decode you meant get user auth object then I don't think that's possible. Consider adding some sort of query param in your generated url that'll help your server identify the user.

If you verify the oob code on server instead of using Firebase Client SDK as shown above you'll get the user's email back in response.

Comment: the docs for this are found here, in case you want to expand your usage: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/resetPassword